# Toggling a button in panda3d

Tags: python, panda3d

How would you put a button in the ‘down’ state on the first click and in the ‘normal’ state on the second click? And would you make this out of a DirectButton or a DirectCheckButton? This is what I’ve tried so far.

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from direct.gui.DirectGui import *

class Core(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)
        ButtonBar()


class ButtonBar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.makebtns()

    def makebtns(self):
        self.btnsr = DirectButton(command=self.toggle)
        self.btnsr['extraArgs'] = [self.btnsr]

    def toggle(self,me):
        if me['state'] == 'normal':
            me['state'] = 'down'


core = Core()
core.run()
```

Changing the state to ‘down’ freezes the Button because its not a valid state. How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the panda3d discourse. Answer by Thaumaturge is below

Hmm… I’m not sure that DirectButton’s “state” field is what you’re looking for, but rather the “setState” method of PGItem. Either way, the appropriate state isn’t “down”, but rather “DGG.BUTTON_DEPRESSED_STATE” (which has the value “1”). Similarly, the “ready” (i.e. unpressed) state is “DGG.BUTTON_READY_STATE” (which has the value “0”).

In short, you might try a command like this:

```
myDirectButton.node().setState(DGG.BUTTON_DEPRESSED_STATE)
```